# Rest Specification : Need help understanding Equivalent Representation

Tags: rest, put

I would like any help in better understanding the Equivalent Representation of Json Structure.

**Excerpts from REST spec**

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be
>   created or replaced with the state defined by the representation
>   enclosed in the request message payload.  A successful PUT of a given 
>   representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same
>   target resource will result in an equivalent representation being
>   sent in a 200 (OK) response

The spec suggest we return equivalent representation of an object.

Is following jsons, equivalent representations ?

**Representation 1**

```
Person
{
  "name":"foo",
  "age": 25,
  "details" : {
    "gender":"male"
  }
}
```

**Representation 2**

```
Person
{
  "name":"foo",
  "age": 25,
  "gender":"male"
}
```

Comment: No, they're not

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen  why ? Please elaborate.

Comment: I would think it's obvious why they're not equivalent. They're different.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I know from the looks of it , it is different , but i am trying to understand nuance of it .  Heres an Example  An Equivalent binary representation of a decimal number 2 is 010 .   Based on this analogy isnt both jsons are equivalent representations . yes they different structure, but the values are same , hence are they not equivalent ?

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation I've seen comes from [Darrel Miller](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/api-craft/S5cyzl6xWVA/pctyTQpxLrMJ):

> There is nothing that precludes a server from adding immutable information to
> the representation.  What the client sent, and what the server returns from the GET are still "equivalent" representations from the perspective of the client.

I think the most straight forward cases are those where the server might take a resource and re-express it in a canonical form: for instance, adding or removing pretty-printing of a json document.

In your example, where the two documents follow a different schema, I wouldn't expect that the representations would be considered equivalent.